# VBA Copy/Paste Cell Content (Error 13)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with Excel 365 and try to copy cell contents in VBA.
In the following formula I get an error 13 because the target is of type 'Variant/Integer' and the source of 'Variant/String':

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(NewRow, ColumnCounter).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, ColumnCounter).Value
```

How can I fix this? Why is the target cell (of a newly inserted row) suddenly formatted as integer?

If I alternatively try:

```
tbl.ListRows(CurrentRow).Range.Copy
Set NewRow = tbl.ListRows.Add(TargetRow)
NewRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

I get the error:

> 1004: paste special method of range class failed

Comment: What's the `.Range.` doing in that line?

Answer (score 0):

Open a completely new Excel and try this:

```
Public Sub HereComesTheCode()

    Dim a As Long: a = 1
    Dim b As Long: b = 2
    Dim c As Long: c = 3
    Dim d As Long: d = 4

    ActiveSheet.Cells(a, b).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(c, d).Value

End Sub
```

Then check what are the values in `ColumnCounter`, `CurrentRow` and `NewRow` in your code.